# How to overlay Pine Script indicator, but have it display according to a leftside percentage scale (100% to -100%)?

Tags: pine-script

I want to overlay my indiactor on the chart, but have it sized and scaled to a 100% to -100% scale on the lefthand side.

Here is a screenshot of the type of chart I'm trying to recreate (price is scaled to right side, the indicator is scaled to left percentage):

[image]

And here is another screenshot that has been zoomed in on a shorter timeframe:

[image]

I thought I should use `scale=scale.left` but that doesn't seem to work. It still displays according to the price scale on the right, thus pushing price way higher.

Here is my code:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Initialize External Data", overlay=true, scale=scale.left)

// Dates must appear in chronological order and match chart dates.
// The limit of lines is ~900. Variables used in your calcs will decrease this amount.
float data = na
timestamp = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, hour, minute)
data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 11, 01, 00) ? 100 : data
data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 11, 10, 05) ? 90 : data
data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 11, 20, 10) ? 50 : data
data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 12, 00, 15) ? -70 : data
data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 12, 01, 20) ? -100 : data

plot(data, "data", color.fuchsia, 2)
```

And here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing on TradingView:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this msyelf. The original code works.

But on Tradingview you havet to delete the startegy/study and then click "add to chart" again. Simply saving it does not change it's display like it normally would.